# Can i add a progress bar in the Sharepoint Online Team site page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to add a progress bar in our SharePoint Online Team site page just like the picture below. Anyone knows how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a free app in SharePoint store named **Mavention Profile Completeness** may meet your requirement.
[image]

It will be displayed like below if I add it to my page as a web part.
[image]